# securitypolicy Policy is not a <wsp:Policy> element

Tags: java, maven, wso2, ws-security

I have this security error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Policy is not a <wsp:Policy> element.
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:176)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:100)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.WSS10Builder.build(WSS10Builder.java:40)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.WSS10Builder.build(WSS10Builder.java:33)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:100)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SecureConversationTokenBuilder.build(SecureConversationTokenBuilder.java:70)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SecureConversationTokenBuilder.build(SecureConversationTokenBuilder.java:31)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:100)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.ProtectionTokenBuilder.build(ProtectionTokenBuilder.java:39)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.ProtectionTokenBuilder.build(ProtectionTokenBuilder.java:34)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:100)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SymmetricBindingBuilder.build(SymmetricBindingBuilder.java:41)
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SymmetricBindingBuilder.build(SymmetricBindingBuilder.java:36)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:100)
```

When I try to evaluate this element inside my webservicesecurity policy:

```
<sp:Policy xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                                                        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                                                        <sp:RequireSignatureConfirmation />
                                                    </sp:Policy>
```

In this method:

```
private Policy getPolicyOperator(Object element) {
    QName qn = factory.getConverterRegistry().findQName(element);

    if (Constants.isPolicyElement(qn)) {
        String ns = qn.getNamespaceURI();
        return (Policy) processOperationElement(element, new Policy(defaultPolicyRegistry, ns));
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(qn + " is not a <wsp:Policy> element."); 
}
```

In class PolicyBuilder in neethi 3.0.2 dependency.

I see the error in this method:

```
public static boolean isPolicyNS(String ns) {
    return URI_POLICY_13_NS.equals(ns)
        || URI_POLICY_15_DEPRECATED_NS.equals(ns)
        || URI_POLICY_15_NS.equals(ns);
}
```

because this namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy it´s not a PolicyNS.

I use this maven dependencies in my project:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
          <artifactId>rampart-trust</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
          <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>opensaml1</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
          <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.1.wso2v10</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Any idea??

Comment: WSO2 Carbon products are released with Neethi 2.0.4 which is compatible with axis2 1.6.1.wso2v10. I believe Neethi 3.x is not compatible with axis2 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in this case is with the generation of the policy in the server side. for example:

```
        <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                <sp:RequireSignatureConfirmation/>
            </sp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
```

It must be:

```
        <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                <sp:RequireSignatureConfirmation/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
```

This little change solve the problem.
check this out: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-dev/201110.mbox/%3CCAJW3xdrg=iUrpLGE+AOjayin_Jkxjv-0A7xOZRV1y08961zsWQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: hello  can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872116/securing-soap-webservices-with-apache-rampart)  question